# How does javascript object property get hoisted?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, console.log

Here is the code-

```
function setOptions(obj, options) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty('options')) {
        obj.options = obj.options ? create(obj.options) : {};
    }
    for (var i in options) {
        obj.options[i] = options[i];
    }
    return obj.options;
}
var x={};
setOptions(x, {prop1:2});
console.log(x);
setOptions(x,{prop1:3});
console.log(x);
```

I expected that the first `setOptions()` call should assign a `prop1:2` property to `x` . And second `setOptions()` call will reassign `prop1` as `3`. According to  my assumption, the output should be-

```
 first console.log output - {prop1:2} 
 second console.log output - {prop2:3}
```

But it is printing the following stuff in web console-

```
 first console.log output - {prop1:3} 
 second console.log output - {prop2:3}
```

What am I missing in my assumption?

Comment: Nothing, it's due to unintuitive browser handling of logging objects live. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` instead.

Comment: This is one of the reasons not to stumble around in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you can *turn on the lights* with a debugger. :-) Stepping through with the debugger built into your browser or IDE would show you that the code is doing what you expect it to do, whereas (as CertainPerformance pointed out), `console.log`'s deferred evaluation can catch you out. (When you *have* to use `console.log`, to log something as of a certain point in time, often `console.log(JSON.stringify(theThing));` is useful.)

Comment: Thank you so much .  :-)